# z-index issue. cannot get section to float above chat widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am editing a website and attempting to get the footer copyright information to float above the chat widget on mobile display. 
[Click here to see floating index problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSUL6.png)
I have attempted to add custom css tags and play with different div surrounding the footer and nothing has worked.

```
div.et_pb_text_inner {
z-index: 99999;
position: relative;
}

 h50  {
z-index: 99999;
position: relative;
 }
```

The end result is that the copyright info flaots above the chat icon that floats on the lower right hand of the screen.

the website in question can be accessed at https://www.pilotrg.com

Thank You

Comment: So you want to have it scroll lower then the copyright text so that it doesnt end the scroll on top of it? Or you want the text to appear on top of the message Icon? z-index has to deal with stuff overlaying. [Like sticking something on top of something else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index).

Comment: I want the text to appear on top of the message icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
z-index: -1;
```

on chat widget

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot figure out where to even start to add the code to the widget as its a plugin. I am ooen to any ideas.

Comment: You want to hide widget at all? If footer will be on top of widget you couldn’t see it.

Comment: I dont want to hide the widget i juat want the copyright text to appear over the chat icon. So it doesnt get cute off